# If min-max normalization is just a kind of rescaling then why mean is not zero after this rescaling?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, normalization

I have performed Min-Max normalization after which sample ranges in [-1,1]. Since this normalization is just a kind of re-scaling, so why mean is not zero in the new data? Is there anything wrong in my code or is there anything wrong in my explanation?

```
data  np.array([-3, 1,2])
print("data mean:" , data.mean())
#perform min-max normalization:
old_range = np.amax(data) - np.amin(data)
new_range = 2 
new_min = -1    
data_norm = ((data - np.amin(data)) / old_range)*new_range + new_min
print("data_norm:", data_norm)
print("mean after normalization: ", data_norm.mean())

#Result:
#data mean:  0.0
#mean after normalization:  0.60000001
```

Comment: What does "just a kind of re-scaling" mean & why would it imply the mean would be unchanged? We can't point out wrong beliefs if you don't state them clearly & we can't explain wrong reasoning if you don't give it clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general if `x` is a random variable and `y = bx+c` then ([reference](http://davidmlane.com/hyperstat/A59639.html))

```
mean(y) = mean(x)*b + c
std(y) = std(x)*b
variance(y) = variance(x)*b**2
```

[image]

```
x = np.array([-3, 1,2])
new_min = -1
new_max = 1
new_range = new_max - new_min
new_x = ((x-np.min(x))/(np.max(x)-np.min(x)))*new_range + new_min

print ("Mean: {0:.3}, std: {1:.3}, Var: {2:.3}".format(np.mean(new_x), np.std(new_x), np.var(new_x)))

alpha = new_range/(np.max(x)-np.min(x))
beta = np.min(x)*alpha - new_min
new_mean = np.mean(x)*alpha - beta
new_std = np.std(x)*alpha
new_var = np.var(x)*alpha*alpha

print ("Mean: {0:.3}, std: {1:.3}, Var: {2:.3}".format(new_mean,new_std,new_var))
```

Output:

```
Mean: 0.2, std: 0.864, Var: 0.747
Mean: 0.2, std: 0.864, Var: 0.747
```

So mean of y depends on the mean of `x` and alpha and beta as shown in the above equations.

I want to add why standardization of data produces data with mean zero.
[image]

Comment: So the formulas suggest that the mean after rescaling can be different

Comment: @jerr no pleas see the equation for `mean(y)`. The program proves that the equation is correct. First print is mean calculated on the new data generated and the second print is from the question. Please go thought the equations. It will be clear.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: @philipxy sure. It was bit easy for me to write in latex. Any suggestion on how to write equations quickly ?

Answer (score 1):

Normalization usually means to scale a variable to have a values between new_min and new_max(in your case, it's between -1 and 1), while standardization transforms data to have a mean of zero and a standard deviation of 1.

For Instance, let suppose you want to scale your variables between (0, 1), i.e. new_min=0 and new_max=1. Then how in this case, mean will be 0? There is no negative value to cancel out positive value.

Comment: yes I'm familiar with both. But I want to know does after normalizing data [-1,1] ,mean value will shift?. I update my code

Comment: So if I standardize 5 samples to zero mean and 1 standard deviation. Then if again print the mean of first sample then it is not exactly zero.

Comment: check this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10289/whats-the-difference-between-normalization-and-standardization